# What is real name of firebase FCM package

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've copied pre-built code from Firebase [documentations](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/kotlin/MainActivity.kt) and results is like this:

[image: one]

**What should I change `quickstart` to?**

Answer (score 0):

That's determined by your app's package name.  The package name determines where the R class is generated.  We don't have that information available in the question here, so you will have to find it in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: so you mean i should change `quickstart` with my `appName` right?

Comment: this name `package="com.xxx.yyyyy"`?

Comment: Yes, that determines the Java package where your R class gets generated.  It also might be where some other classes are as well.

Comment: unfortunately using that `com` part becomes red, removing `com` then `xxx` part becomes red and so on...

Comment: Then you might have some other problems in your project to resolve first.